# Нет текста письма в почте Yandex python

Tags: python, email, smtp, mime, яндекс-почта

В получаемом письме на Яндексе нет текста письма. Текст видно только в ящике в предпросмотре, но когда открываешь письмо то текста нет, только вложение. На других почтовых сервисах все нормально.

1-почта Мэйла

[image: Почта Mail]
2-ящик Яндекса
[image: ящик Яндекса]
3-письмо на Яндексе
[image: письмо на Яндексе]

```
 msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = from_inp + ' <' + sender + '>'
        msg['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)
        msg['Reply-To'] = sender
        msg['Return-Path'] = sender
        msg['X-Mailer'] = 'Python/' + (python_version())

        part_text = MIMEText(text.encode('utf-8'), 'plain', 'utf-8')
        part_html = MIMEText(html.encode('utf-8'), 'html', 'utf-8')
        part_file = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream; name="{}"'.format(basename))
        part_file.set_payload(open(filepath, "rb").read())
        part_file.add_header('Content-Description', basename)
        part_file.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="{}"; size={}'.format(basename, filesize))
        encoders.encode_base64(part_file)
        msg.attach(part_text)
        msg.attach(part_html)
        msg.attach(part_file)

        mail = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(server)
        mail.login(user, password)
        mail.sendmail(sender, recipients, msg.as_string())
        mail.quit()
```

Comment: А что в `text` и `html`?

Comment: `text = '! LOOK AT THAT NEKO! '`
`html = '<p>' + text + '</p>'`